# Suspend not working properly on MacBook Pro Retina (10.1)

Tags: nvidia, suspend, macbook

I am admittedly a newbie user. I have recently got an Ubuntu 13.04 install working on my rMBP (as you can infer from the title) and noticed that suspend doesn't work. The system shuts down properly, but will not resume after reopening the lid and/or pressing keys. After some google searching I stumbled upon someone saying that the nvidia driver work with suspend. If there is in fact no solution for me to stick with my nouveau driver and suspend properly, then how may I go about installing the appropriate nvidia driver? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What Nvidia driver version did you try? What Ubuntu version are you on? What do you mean "will not resume"? What exactly happens? Please edit your question to include more details.

Comment: @gertvdijk thank you for the feedback. I have edited my post as requested, but I have not attempted to install the Nvidia driver yet, so I don't have a version.

Comment: *"I stumbled upon someone saying that the nvidia driver work with suspend"* Well. Just try a recent version. For me on my hardware the Nvidia driver works perfectly fine in suspending. Don't just follow one experience of a single user report. And not all installations/hardware are the same, so results always vary. Anyway, so your question is solely based on this "rumour"?

Comment: @gertvdijk To be more specific, I read someone else's guide to installing Ubuntu on a MacBook Pro Retina (10.1). This is my specific case so I thought it would work. The only difference was the version of Ubuntu they installed. http://cberner.com/2012/10/19/installing-ubuntu-12-10-on-macbook-pro-retina/

Comment: Bump, I have yet to find the solution to my problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That guide is almost a year old. Just try the 13.04 and a more recent Nvidia driver. Your "problem" right now is based on what you read, not about your actual experience. That's not very constructive. Please just try and support your question with facts. How to install an Nvidia driver is all over this site, really - use the search.

Comment: try to update your distro to recent one, mine got fixed after an update...

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. Seems that the nouveau driver for nvidia is buggy. So all you have to do is switch to integrated intel card and disable the nvidia card.

Make sure xserver-xorg-video-intel package is installed

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Switch to the integrated card: I couldn't do that from Linux. [Not sure if there is a simple way in Ubuntu to achieve this]
I booted Mac OSX, installed gfxcardstatus app from http://graphic-card-status.mac.informer.com/2.1/ and then set it to "Integrated Only".

Reboot to ubuntu. Suspend/resume should work like a charm